# Validate Cross website request - Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have scenario where My webpage is requested by another website. That website will have Hyperlink to my webpage.

I Need to check whether request is coming from valid website or not. I have done this by checking URL Referer of that website, and working fine.

Another way to validate this request is to validate client certificate(x.509).

I want to know which is the best/secure way to validate referer website? Is there any other way to validate referer site excepting url referer and certificate validation?

Thanks
Fenil

Answer (score 0):

The client certificate would identify the person clicking on the link, but not the referring page, so it should be ruled out.

As for the referrer, it does work, but with a couple of caveats:
1 - it's not secure (for big values of "secure"). The http_referrer is an optional field that the browser inserts in the request for your site. So it's controlled at the client's side and can be easily forged. So, if the level of security you want is "make sure that somebody has not posted my link on another page, where unaware users may click on it" then you're quite fine with checking the referrer. If you're relying on this for anything more (like making sure the incoming person is authorized to do something on your site) then you probably want a form of user authentication

2- some software that may be installed on your users' computers (like "Norton Internet Security") masks the http_referrer out of privacy concerns, so some of your users may not have a http_referrer.